# Show image in ajax from FileResult Handler (Action)

Tags: c#, jquery, css, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

i using Asp.net Core Razor Page for my Current Project ... I have a Page-Handler (Action) for send image to my page with Ajax ... I send request with ajax to my handler and my response is Suitable image to page but image dont show in my img src tag !

```
public IActionResult OnGetDeleteImage(ImageType imageType)
{
    return File(DefaultImage(imageType), "image/png", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
}
```

... DefaultImage get image path on server .
and ajax request :

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: deleteImagePath,
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
            $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
    },

    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);  
            $("#" + id).attr("src",data);

    },
    error: function (err) {
        alert(err);
    }
```

my code return image content but dont show that in img src .
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to place the binary contents of the image into the `src` attribute which expects a url, not the actual data.  You can try to format that image as data url and it should work.

I am assuming your `DefaultImage` method returns a path to a PNG file in this example, but I can't tell that for sure.  To return a data uri, it would look something like this:

```
public IActionResult OnGetDeleteImage(ImageType imageType)
{
    return new ContentResult() {
       Content = "data:image/png;base64," + System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(DefaultImage(imageType))),
       ContentType = "text/plain"
    });
}
```

Data uri only works on images up to 32K in IE browsers, and the code above isn't very efficient.

If possible (e.g. the image is stored in part of your server-side app that can be served up as static files), it would be best if you could return a publicly accessible uri to the image file on the C# method, and then the browser would download the file from that uri when you updated `src`.  That would look like this:

```
public IActionResult OnGetDeleteImage(ImageType imageType)
{
    return new ContentResult() {
       Content=GetPublicPathTo(DefaultImage(imageType)), //this should return something like "/img/the_image_to_display.png"
       ContentType="text/plain"
    }
}
```